# How do we distinguish between "the dog's bones" and "the dogs' bones" in verbal communication?

Tags: grammar

**Technicality** Well, technically what am really asking (which is too long/complex to go as a title) is: How do you distinguish between singular and plural possessive nouns when the thing in possession is plural?

**Content** Ok, so lets backtrack a little. You have singular/plural possessives, and singular/plural possessions (sorry for my ill terminology, am still learning). You can distinguish between all 4 possibilities in written communication. In oral communication, you can only seem to distinguish 2. Take the sentences "the dog's bones", and "The dogs' bones". So of course, the difference lies in the placement of the apostrophe. However, in oral communication, there's no difference in the way that "dog's" and " dogs' " in pronounced (unless I've *seriously* overlooked something). So, there's still 4 possibilities, but 2 of them are expressed in the same manner since dog's and dogs' is pronounced in the same manner, yet can mean either a single dog or a group of dogs.

**Possible Solution** I suppose one way around this is to perhaps state the plural possessive as something like 'the dogs-es bones', instead of just 'the dogs bones'. It 'feels' like a plural, as if there's multiple dogs. Though of course, this is itself ambiguous, since you could still interpret the pronunciation 'dog-es' as being just a single dog in possession of something.

**Passing thought**: I find it interesting how this problem simply doesn't arise when you change the structure of the very word itself to distinguish plural nouns from their singular counterpart e.g "the man's bones vs the "men's bones".

Comment: Presumably, the only time it would be important to distinguish the two noun phrases is when zombies aren't walking around saying the two isolated phrases but instead the two phrases are part of a discourse that containes all sorts of clues as to which  is meant, even if both are part of that discourse.

Comment: The same way that you distinguish *any* homophones: **context**.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to distinguish these, you can just say "the bones that belong to the dog" or "the bones that belong to the dogs." Or "the bones of the dog" or "the bones of the dogs" (you would have to use "of" if you're referring to the bones inside the dogs' bodies).

Most of the time, you don't need to distinguish singular and plural.

"The dogs-es bones" is not grammatical in standard English, and sounds silly.

Comment: Absolutely correct although, personally I prefer the 'bones of the dog' structure as it is more economical.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this causes no confusion here is for the same reason that people know what the implicit subject is in pro-drop languages, or which word is meant when hearing homophones: the surrounding context makes obvious just what is being referred to.

That’s because if it does not, one simply does not phrase it that way.